# Optimize select query for non-indexed view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to select rows from non-indexed view by their IDs.
Here is view definition:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[_V_V3] 
AS 
SELECT (CONVERT(varchar,T1.PK_ID)+','+CONVERT(varchar,T2.PK_ID)) as ID,
T1.[Id] as [T1_Id],
T1.[V1] as [T1_V1],
T2.[Id] as [T2_Id],
T2.[V1] as [T2_V1] 
FROM [T1]  INNER JOIN [T2] ON (T2.V1=T1.V1)
```

where T2.V1, T1.V1 - nvarchar.

My select query:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[_V_V3] WHERE ID IN ('1,1', '2,3', ....)
```

It works very slowly. With 1000 IDs this query could perform several minutes.

Is there any way to optimize this select?

Comment: Do you have an index (including primary key or unique constraint) on the T1 and T2 V1 columns?  SQL Server ought to be able the optimize the query encapsulated in the view based in indexes on the underlying tables.\

Comment: Indexes are on T1.PK_ID and T2.PK_ID. T2.V1 and T1.V1 - without indexes.

Comment: do you have access to the tables?

Comment: Since you are joining on V1 rather than PK_ID, you need an additional index on those columns to optimize the join.  I would still expect index scans due to the non-sargable expression but this will at least facilitate a merge join.  There is no solution that can use the `WHERE` in the outer query without materializing the expression value with a view index because of multiple tables are needed to compute the value.

Comment: no index can help here. the query uses a calculated column to select the rows. this forces the db to calculate each possible row before it can filter the output

Comment: The query shouldn't take that much time for 1000 IDs, considering that both T1 and T2 containt about miliion records each. The problem may  come from poor administration of your database, check this tips for fragmentation issues: http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2009/03/20/sql-server-2008-fragmentation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do this:

**View**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[_V_V3] 
AS
T1.PK_ID as PK_ID1,
T2.PK_ID as PK_ID2,
T1.[Id] as [T1_Id],
T1.[V1] as [T1_V1],
T2.[Id] as [T2_Id],
T2.[V1] as [T2_V1] 
FROM [T1]  INNER JOIN [T2] ON (T2.V1=T1.V1)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[_V_V3] 
WHERE
    ( 
        PK_ID1=1 AND PK_ID2=1
    )
    OR
    (
        PK_ID1=2 AND PK_ID2=3
    )
```

I would think that an integer compare is fast then varchar compare

Comment: Unfortunately view doesn't contain PK_ID for each source table. The only thing I have is a string (ID) that contains IDs divided by commas.

Comment: and you cant change that view?

Comment: Nope :(. These views are generated programmatically. Basically application can generate view joined by any column.